# VS Code Problems tab: Clear items coming from tasks with problemMatcher

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-problem-matcher

I have a few VS Code tasks with a [problem matcher](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher). When I run them, they work as expected, i.e., (re)populate the Problems tab with messages accordingly. Owner is always set.

However, is there a way to clear the items without restarting/reloading VS Code?

While not ideal, an extra task would work for me just fine.

I am not sure I am using this feature right. Since this particular flow is kind of manual, as it doesn't reflect subsequent changes in code unless I run the task again, I'd expect to be able to reset as well, and preferably keep items coming from extensions.

I've read some posts on the topic here and on GitHub, but couldn't find a straight answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: You did well to specify `owner`. If you don't do that, then the problems matched by the task will not be cleared when the task is re-run (see also [issue ticket #164751](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164751)).

As far as I know, at the time of this writing, there is no way to get what you want. What I'd suggest to do is take a look at the existing feature-request issue ticket surrounding related functionality and see if any request something you'd like to get implemented (I think any one of these would solve the problem- they're just different ways of doing it):

- [Have a command that clears all problems that are from tasks. #77214](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77214)

  - Historically related discussion: [Clear problems using a task
    #50448](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50448)
- [Regex pattern to clear all problems of a task owner #73186](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73186)
- [Clear all problems in the 'Problems' pane with a button #66982](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66982)

I suggest that you give those issue tickets a thumbs up to show support for them. You can also subscribe to them to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a way out of this problem: you can set the `owner` field of your ProblemMatcher to some arbitrary value (please note that you don't want this value to clash with an extension name).

When you have done this thing, VSCode will now detect problems coming out from one onwer, so it will remove problems that have gone away and won't duplicate the existing ones.

Comment: it's not clear to me what you're describing. is it supposed to mean that after a task's problem matcher matches something, changing the problem matcher's owner member value causes the previously matched problems to be forgotten? because that's not what happens for me...

Comment: @starball, no, that's not what I mean. What I mean is that you have to set the `onwer` field to _some_ non-default value (it just has to be somewhat else than the default "external" string) once. So when you set it to your arbitary value, all problems generated by this matcher are now associated with your owner.

Comment: how does that help? how does that allow clearing those problems without rerunning the task after fixing the problems?